# Connectivity between 2 Oracle RDS instances in AWS on 2 private subnets in 2 VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

Is there a way to connect one database in a private subnet in a VPC to another database in a private subnet in another VPC? Both have same master account but separate accounts each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with [VPC Peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html).

A direct connection between the VPCs is established and all traffic is conducted with private IPV4 addresses.  You can even do this with VPCs in different regions, where the traffic is encrypted and routed via the AWS backbone.

Peering is established when the Owner of the first VPC sends a peering request to the owner of the second VPC, and they can reside in different accounts.

[image]

Comment: But both are in different accounts, do we need to give cross account role or just vpc peering would suffice?

Comment: It works with different accounts. The Owner of one of the VPCs sends a peering request to the owner of the second VPC.

Comment: Thank you so much, it cleared my doubt. I have few more questions on different topics of AWS. Will ask them in different thread.